# Socket I/O processing (high-traffic)

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, io

I'm working on a high-traffic network program that uses Tcp sockets. I think I need 3 threads for this system.

- **Tcp main listening:** select() based I/O handling
- **In data processing class:** handling packets, selecting sockets for sending output data (for game/char systems etc.)
- **Out data processing class:** I'll send data with send() method that is blocking method, so I need to implement a loop (while/for) and this loop will take a while to process and I wont slow down in data processing, I'll implement this data processing class for socket send loop.

Now I'm going to implement a network hierarchy like this but I'm note sure to create a out data processing class. Do I need this for improve network performance? Otherwise, any other suggession for improving network performance? (maybe I can't see something)

**PLUS:** I'm packing incoming Tcp packets for handling a complete packet from client which is a special packet like game RPC positioning, custom request etc.

Comment: Define "high traffic". How many simultaneous clients? How much bandwidth?

Comment: @syam 1024 clients, avarage 1024clients*5kb*5(0.2sec) = 25Mb input per second. 25mb*1024clients = 25Gb output per second.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it's 25Mb not 25Gb per second (you multiplied twice by 1024 clients, it should only have been once). And 25Mb/s is pretty much nothing nowadays, you can choose whatever architecture you want. One thread per connection, select, asio, whatever... All will absorb the load without flinching. As far as **I** am concerned, for such light loads I like to use one thread per connection, makes it much easier to manage.

Comment: @syam namely for 1024 clients, I can create 1024 thread? Right?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'd do. Each time `accept` gives you a new socket, create a new thread to handle just that connection. As a side note, 1024 clients at 25Kb/s is far from "high traffic". Make it 10k clients and we're beginning to talk... ;)

Comment: @syam :D OMG! I was under the impression that 1024 thread will be slowdown CPU and that isn't suitable for networking-programming. If you don't worn me now, I'm goint to create only 3 threads :) 50.000 clients is high-traffic that is ok, but is 1GB~ input high-traffic or what is high-traffic?

Comment: Well the thing with network programming is that threads spend most of the time waiting for I/O operations so you have a lot of room before you actually saturate the CPU. The real question is, which is the **scarcest** resource (CPU, disk, network, ...)? Unfortunately, only benchmarks can give you a real answer. As to the definition of "high traffic", it's hard to say... I for one would set the bar around 100Mb/s (1Gbps) but that's just a random estimation, there is no definitive definition. ;)

Comment: Just want to mention that 1024 threads will eat 1 GB of RAM because of 1 MB allocated for each thread stack. You'd better use ThreadPool, Queues, etc...