# Handling 7000+ clients? -MultiThreading (TCP, high-traffic)

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm going to create a network system that can handle 7000+ tcp socket client with **5KB/s** input (clients sends). I've looked into this question: [Link>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369322/socket-i-o-processing-high-traffic). They said "create 1024 thread to handle 1024 clients". I know there is a method named ***"select()"*** and I think I can't open 7000+ threads to handle 7000+ clients because my processor (or server) have got only 8CPU and that means 7000+ threads are a big mistake. Now I think I'll create ~1000 thread and I'll handle every 7 socket group in this threads. But now here is the question: If I have same application but I've 2CPU processor, I can't get maximum performance with 1000 threads, I should create (maybe) 500 threads. Otherwise if I've 8CPU processor, I can't get max. performance with 1000 threads and I need to create (maybe) 2000 threads to handle sockets. How can I understand "this processor can handle X threads"? And is this way true?

**EDIT:** I think I can create a profiller that is watching program. Namely, every thread logging "I have finished my job in X seconds." and profiller handling this messages and decides to create a thread or killing a thread. But how to understand threads' (or CPU) status?

Comment: Everything over tens of threads is per core is going to severly bog down the system. Also read about the [C10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

Comment: Create as many threads as there are CPUs and go fully asynchronous.

Comment: @usr Namely 8CPU = 8Threads to handle sockets? That means 8x1024(for select method) = 8k clients?

Comment: Not sure where the 1024 number is coming from. Modern OS's support async IO. You don't block threads at all. You get called back by the OS whenever work needs to be done. On Windows this is straight-forward and I assume on Linux as well. Get to know the APIs.

Comment: For doing this in a platform-independent way, you can have a look at boost asio for a start.

Comment: @usr The number 1024 comes from the `select` call, which traditionally only can handle 1024 descriptors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way a single server can handle 35 Gb/sec traffic (and even if there is, it will be extremely expensive).

The way I'd approach this problem is:

- Understand API
- Understand protocols, select the best one for the job
- Understand compression, security aspects (encryption, authentication), licensing
- Figure out how you going to load balance your servers
- Write a prototype server and client
- Generate some load on the server and understand limitations of a single instance
- Hide N servers behind load balancers and observe their behaviour

Things you want to concentrate from the first line of code:

- How you going to scale this horizontally
- What are your performance metrics

**Edit**

So it's in **KB**, which is much better :). I would still recommend thinking about LB upfront.

There are different technologies and protocols to help you write efficient application. From personal experience I would prefer HTTP to TCP. There are many good load balancers available, adding compression, encryption, authentication is matter of days.

I also heard [node.js](http://nodejs.org) is superfast if you do any IO operations for processing client requests.

The servers that I wrote were ASP.NET Web API applications, each processing a few MB/sec. It was trivial to hide servers behind load balancers (I used [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) and [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) but surely there are many others available. I also worked with C++ socket server and the development time for it was considerably longer. My point is, if you can use a high-level language, prefer it to lower-level language. This will shorten you dev time (in my case by a factor of 10x!) and make life easier.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. It isn't **5Mb/s**, it is **5Kb/s**. And I think I understood it. The main _keyword_ is **LoadBalancing**!

Comment: Just as an anecdote, I'm currently processing 130 Mb/sec with a single nginx.

Comment: Dev. time isn't an issue for me now. And my system will run like a MMO game server. **EDIT:** My app. should be _low-level_.

Comment: @PilawyerDev It was considerably slower to develop c++ server, roughly 10x times. But maybe this is due to my limited experience with c++.

Comment: As oleksii says, run perf tests on your server from day 0. Modern async  I/O styles on today's platforms will easily scale to the numbers you talk about and it's what YOUR code does to squander that scalability that you should be interested in. I wrote about this here: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/how-to-support-10000-or-more-concurrent-tcp-connections---part-2---perf-tests-from-day-0.html

Comment: @oleksii I'm going to create async+non block sockets, after load-balancing. I always watch performance test while I'm developing. Is this a true way? :)

Comment: @PilawyerDev there is just so many things that can go wrong. As with any other multithreading tasks it's very easy to mess up. Do use test driven development, write a lot of tests. Watch for memory corruption, be very careful with it - it's easy to mess up and very difficult to find the problem. I guess there is no a *true way*, but the one that works for you and solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is what does the server do? Will it be cpu bound or IO bound during each client request?

If it is CPU bound then there is little point trying to process them all in parallel since you not have any more concurrency than the number of cores on the server. In this case you may as well just create as many threads as there are cores on the server and process the inputs serially as fast as you can.

If the server process is IO bound then you need to determine how long each thread that's handling a client request will be idle for, that will give you an idea of how many threads it makes sense to create. That's the classic approach, but as others have pointed out, in this case the more contemporary approach would be to use an asynchronous programming library. For C++ on Windows that would be PPL.

UPDATE

You seem pretty keen to stay low level, so to get right to the core of your original question, which is how to calculate how many threads can a core support.

First you'd create wrapper functions for any blocking calls the thread calls (which log the time each thread is blocked). From those metrics you can determine the average thread occupancy, and once you know that obtaining a rough calculation of the optimal number of threads is easy enough.

```
thread_occupancy = (thread_run_time - thread_blocked_time) / thread_run_time
optimal_thread_count = num_cores / thread_occupancy
```

You'd probably want to add at least 0.1 (10%) to thread_occupancy to cover thread switching overhead.

But, as others have said, this classic multi-threading approach only works well for a few tens of threads. Once the OS has to control the scheduling of a hundred threads or so then the scheduling overhead increases to the extent that adding more threads brings no benefits. The point at which this occurs though is highly system and software dependent, so you just have to do some testing to hit the sweet spot.

If your operations are IO bound enough that you wish to process hundreds or thousands of requests simultaneously then you have no choice but to handle multiple requests per thread using asynchronous processing, which normally mandates the use of an asynchronous library. In this case you'll usually have one thread per core running fully occupied under the control of the asynchronous library. This might be handled by the library itself or you might need to set it up manually, but either way no run time controlling of the number of threads is necessary so while you could monitor thread occupancy the same way as the purely multi-threaded approach there wouldn't be much for you to do with that information.

Comment: Both. There is a world simulation in the server-side and an announcement to "Hey something updated clients!".

Comment: What part of that is IO bound, DB access or something?